# performing a fuzzy search using elasticsearch not working as expected for special names

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

i'm trying to use fuzzy search in order to find artist names such as 'p!nk' with the query 'pink'. i'm indexing the artists name field with a standard analyzer and performing the fuzzy search like the following example. however it returns strange results. see below ...

```
{
  "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "artists": "pink"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "artists": {
                            "query": "pink",
                            "fuzziness": "1"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

i'm doing both a 'should' query and a 'fuzzy' query so i can cover all bases and they get scored appropriately. (not sure if this is correct either).

but the results i get are very strange. the artist 'p!nk' is definitely in my index, as i can retrieve it using a regular query on the correct spelling of 'p!nk', but 'pink' doesn't find it.

here's my results:

```
hits": {
 "total": 4,
 "max_score": 4.479847,
 "hits": [
     {
        "_index": "myindex",
        "_type": "mytype",
        "_id": "723721728656",
        "_score": 4.479847,
        "fields": {
           "artists": [
              "Pink Martini"
           ]
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "myindex",
        "_type": "mytype",
        "_id": "888837349727",
        "_score": 0.9021777,
        "fields": {
           "artists": [
              "Kid Ink"
           ]
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "myindex",
        "_type": "mytype",
        "_id": "888837168625",
        "_score": 0.7237221,
        "fields": {
           "artists": [
              "Daft Punk"
           ]
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "myindex",
        "_type": "mytype",
        "_id": "888837168618",
        "_score": 0.7237221,
        "fields": {
           "artists": [
              "Daft Punk"
           ]
        }
     }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chances are the `!` is being removed, as well as other special characters by the analyzer you have applied.  Try using the [analyze API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html#indices-analyze) on your index and see how `p!nk` is being tokenized.

Comment: greg, it says it's being tokenized as 'p' and separately as 'nk'... {
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "p",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 1,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "nk",
         "start_offset": 2,
         "end_offset": 4,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 2
      }
   ]
} ... i'm using a custom analyzer which is using 'snowball', 'stop', and 'lowercase' filters, and a 'standard' tokenizer

Comment: Right, so that is likely the issue here.  You'll have to play with different tokenizers/filters to find what works best for you.  A good start would be to try replacing the standard tokenizer with whitespace.

Comment: still learning ... so i don't fully understand what p and nk are supposed to be telling me.

Comment: Hey @bigerock, those are the individual tokens that are actually being stored in the index for the term `p!nk`.  Your analyzer is splitting on the `!` character, so the entire term `p!nk` as a single token doesn't actually exist, which is why you can't search for it.

Comment: ok - not sure which analyzer/indexing solution to use here. i understand synonyms would work, but i don't want to have to reindex every time i want to add a new one. also fuzzy searches would work, but i don't really want to return 'link' when someone types 'pink', for example.